# jQuery: set focus to input field after slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am displaying a div after a user clicks on the link and the div has a form in it. I need to set the focus on one of the fields once the div with the form is displayed. I have the following code which is not working.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
$( "#myLink" ).click(function() {
    $( ".search-container" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) 
        {
            $("#searchField").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/j2bebc7j/ Are you expecting a different behavior?

Comment: Must be something else on my page that's not allowing the focus to work then :)  Thanks for adding to jsfiddle, looks like it's another issue and not the code above.